# getting variables outside if statement

Tags: php

Hi guys I have a problem with getting a variable outside and after an if statement. Little code explanation: `$gameid` or `$id` is sent via ajax to this file. Now `$id` have always a value and `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` is true. The insert and select querys work very well. The problem is that I cant get the variable `$answer` or `$question[0]['question'];` after the second if statement. I can get them when I change the second `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` to `else {` but then anyhow there become two rows in my database inserted, the first is right and the second one is empty. Now why cant I get the variables `$answer` and `$question[0]['question'];` after the second if condition?

The error log shows: Notice undefined variable question.

```
<?php

$hostname='localhost';
$user='';
$password='';
if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {
    $gameid = $_GET['gameid'];
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
}
if (isset($_GET['questionid'])) {
    $questionid = $_GET['questionid'];
}
$new = 0;

if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socame",$user,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM questions_de 
                WHERE id = '$questionid'
                LIMIT 1";

        if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
            // then after fetchColumn
            $question = $res->fetchAll();
        }

        if($question > 0) {
            //do something
        } else {
            echo "Sorry something happen wrong with our servers.";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    }

    if ($question[0]["answerm²"] == 0 && $question[0]["answerm³"] == 0) {
        $answer = "answer_m";
    } else {
        $answer = "answerm³";
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socame",$user,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        $sql = "SELECT username 
                FROM user 
                WHERE id = '$id' 
                LIMIT 1";

        if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
            // then after fetchColumn
            $user2name = $res->fetchAll();
        }

        if($user2name > 0) {
            //do something
        } else {
            echo "Sorry something happen wrong with our servers.";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {


    }

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socame",$user,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM questions_de
                LIMIT 1"; // 
        if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
            // then after fetchColumn
            $question = $res->fetchAll();
        }

        if($question > 0) {
            //do something
        } else {

            echo "Sorry something happen wrong with our servers.";
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {

    }


    if ($question[0]["answerm²"] == 0 && $question[0]["answerm³"] == 0) {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socame",$user,$password);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
            $sql = "INSERT INTO game_create (user1, user2, user1name, user2name, question, questionid, answer)
                    VALUES ('".$_COOKIE["userid"]."', '".$id."', '".$_COOKIE["username"]."', '".$user2name[0]["username"]."', '".$question[0]['question']."', '".$question[0]['id']."', '".$question[0]['answer_m']."')";

            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                //echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
            } else{
                // echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
            }

            $new = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if ($new > 0) {

        } else {
            echo 'Sorry something went wrong.';
        }
        $answer = "answer_m";
    }
    else  {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socame",$user,$password);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
            $sql = "INSERT INTO game_create (user1, user2, user1name, user2name, question, questionid, answer)
                    VALUES ('".$_COOKIE["userid"]."', '".$id."', '".$_COOKIE["username"]."', '".$user2name[0]["username"]."', '".$question[0]['question']."', '".$question[0]['id']."', '".$question[0]['answer_m³']."')";

            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                //echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
            } else{
                // echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
            }
            $new = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if ($new > 0) {

        } else {
            echo 'Sorry something went wrong.';
        }
        $answer = "answerm³";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `$_GET['gameid']` has a default value which is getting send to the PHP file?

Comment: +Bas Sorry but I dont know what you mean.

Comment: Does `$_GET['gameid']` have a value when it reaches this php script?

Comment: Yes but it have only a value when ´$_GET['id']´ have no value :)

Comment: But you're stating that `$_GET_['id]` always has a value, therefor, `$_GET['gameid']` wont have a value. And the `$gameid` variable won't be initialized. This means that it won't get past the `isset($_GET['gameid'])` condition, since it's not set.

Comment: Yes thats true but now I send always only the variable ´id´ for testing and not ´gameid´.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {..}
```

You're checking if the `$_GET['gameid']` is set, with other words, if it has a value. As you stated, `$_GET['gameid']` only has a value when `$_GET_[id]` doesn't have value. As you said, `$_GET_['id]` always has value, so `$_GET['gameid']` wont be initialized.

Therefor, it won't get past this condition, and won't reach the line of `$question = $res->fetchAll();`, which initializes the variable.

The same thing stands for `$answer`, since it's in the same if statement and is also doing conditional checking on the `$question` variable.

To solve this problem, either initialize the `$_GET['gameid']` variable by sending it to the PHP script without any conditions or remove the `if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {..}` statement.

Comment: I try to understand it but ´$question = $res->fetchAll();´ and ´$answer´ are too in the second if statement and ´$_GET_['id]´ have only for testing always a value after it it could be that it has no value and ´$_GET['gameid']´ have one. Am I right that your answer isnt right then? But many thanks for your attempt to help me.

Comment: Where are you calling `$question` from?

Comment: In the second ´try´ in ´if (isset($_GET['id'])) {´

Comment: And the code in `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` works well but I cant get the variables outside there.

Comment: You're assigning it if the query runs corectly it in this same `try` statement. Does it get past that if statement? (query). That's because it's out of the scope from the if condition. If you want them to be accessable outside, declare the variables outside the if statement and assign the vars in the if statement.